# Setting 'float' as storage mode of a single precision object

Tags: r

I wish to display the precision of an object as 'float' in R while having single precision. Currently its stored as default type 'double'.

```
timevector=c(1.5,4.5,7.5,10.5,13.5,16.5,19.5,22.5)

typeof(timevector) #displays double
```

But I want to display it as float and having single precision if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> *R has no single precision data type. All real numbers are stored in double precision format.* The functions as.single and single are identical to as.double and double except they set the attribute Csingle that is used in the .C and .Fortran interface, and they are intended only to be used in that context.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.html