# R returns strange order permutation

Tags: r

I am asking for your helps. I was struggling with the way R stores and treats data value. Here is my example:

I have a matrix 4x3. on each row, I calculate the absolute different among each pairs (step 2 in my code):

```
xi_xj[i,1]  = abs(x[i, 1]-x[i, 2]) # the different btw the 1st and 2nd elements

xi_xj[i,2]  = abs(x[i, 1]-x[i, 3]) # the different btw the 1st and 3rd elements

xi_xj[i,3]  = abs(x[i, 2]-x[i, 3]) # the different btw the 2nd and 3rd elements
```

Once the `xi_xj` is computed, I will order 3 elements on each row in an increasing order and return the index or the permutation (step 3 in my code). I use the function `order()` to do this. However, I got strange return permutation for the 4th row of `xi_xj` which containing `(0.3, 0.6,0.3)`. I expect the return permutation should be `{1, 3, 2}` which mean "the first element `(0.3)` comes first, followed by the third element (0.3 as well), and the second comes last (0.6)". When the code running, it returns me strange order {3,1,2}. I was confused here. I have add `#test1` and `#test 2` in my code, and I clearly see that `xi_xj[4,1]` and `xi_xj[4,3]` "slightly different" by an amount of  `1.110223e-16` which is weird. I suspect it is due to the datatype that R auto uses to treat my data, in this case it is "double". I don't know how to work around this.

Here is my code:

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
N=4
M = 3

#1. given X matrix N rows and M cols
(x=matrix(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1,0.2,0.7, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7), nrow=N, ncol=M))


#2. calculate the pairwise distance of each pairs abs(x[k,i]-x[k,j]) in each row kth 
(xi_xj <- matrix(0, nrow =N, ncol = M, byrow = TRUE))
for (i in 1: N){
  xi_xj[i,1]  = abs(x[i, 1]-x[i, 2])
  xi_xj[i,2]  = abs(x[i, 1]-x[i, 3])
  xi_xj[i,3]  = abs(x[i, 2]-x[i, 3])  
}

xi_xj

# 3. In each row, we will need to return the permutation which their value are ordered increasingly.
#create a matrix to store the permutaion or indexing of the increasing order
index_xi_xj = matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=M)
for (i in 1: N){
  #process on each row
  (temp <- xi_xj[i,])

  #get the index of rearangment in increasing order
  index_xi_xj[i,]<- order(temp, decreasing= FALSE)
}
index_xi_xj[4,]
# COMMENT ON THE RESULT: 
# PROBLEM comes from the 4th row of the xi_xj[4, ] containing value {0.3, 0.6, 0.3}. 
# Once R order them in increasing order, we should have CORRECT permutation {1,3,2} 
# of their ordering instead of {3,1,2} as index_xi_xj[4,]


#-------------------------------------------
# 4. test 1: check whether the data in xi_xj[4,1] == xi_xj[4,1] as we see on the console?
xi_xj
if(xi_xj[4,1]==xi_xj[4,3]){
  cat("equal")
}else {print ("different")
       cat("error = ", xi_xj[4,1]-xi_xj[4,3])
}

# 5. test 2: however, if we order the list of c(0.3, 0.6, 0.3), the function "order()" returns correct permutation {1, 3, 2}
(order(c(0.3, 0.6, 0.3), decreasing=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question [Setting 'float' as storage mode of a single precision object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474118/setting-float-as-storage-mode-of-a-single-precision-object). It turns out that R does not support the single precision. Therefore, all values are stored as 'double' which causes the strange sort permutation in my code.